# Using youtube data api in my android project

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to use YouTube data API in my android project.For that I want to use and edit the sample code provided by google itself. What libraries do i need and how can I get them and import them in my project.How do I need to start?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm looking at this myself, this is what I've found so far: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup